# Python3.5 Refuse to Work with MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector, python-3.5, mysql-connector-python

I've read a few questions on here that people are having the same situation as me but no matter what method I tried, it just wouldn't work!

According to MySQL documentation, MySQL-connector-python-2.x.x.x should work with Python 3+.  I've downloaded the RPM package and installed it inside my virtualenv.  However, upon importing the library, I get the error, "No module named MySQL".

Checking to see if I've installed the package:

```
(virtual)[centos ~]$ rpm -ql mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
package mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

Attempting to install the package:

```
(virtual)[centos ~]$ sudo rpm -i ~/Documents/python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for <username>: 
warning: /home/<username>/Documents/python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
    package mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-1.el6.x86_64 is already installed
```

This works on Python2.6:

```
[centos ~]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

Doesn't on Python3.5:

```
[centos ~]$ python3.5
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 13 2016, 17:43:34) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
>>>
```

Verified the package through MySQL documentation:

```
(virtual)[centos]$ python
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 13 2016, 17:43:34) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print (get_python_lib ())
/home/<username>/Documents/redhat-server/python_project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages
>>> 
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
>>>
```

Making sure that python3.5 is in the same directory as MySQL.connector

```
(virtual)[centos]$ which python3.5
~/Documents/redhat-server/python_project/virtual/bin/python3.5
```

**Update:**

```
(virtual)[centos]$ pip install mysql-connector-python
Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python
(virtual)[centos]$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably because your *rpm* installed the package globally and your default python is python2 so python3 won't be able to import that. Also while you're at virtualenv, your python interpreter points to your virtualenv's python binary (either py2/3)... that's why you can't import that under virtualenv neither. One suggestion, try using *pip* to install the package under your virtualenv

Comment: Why are you skipping `import MySQLdb` in your Python3-based snippets?

Comment: @ray - because it's not supported in Python3+.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Comment: @dreamzboy: I have `MySQLdb` installed and working in Python3. In a Ubuntu-based distro, just enter `sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb`. In CentOS6/RHEL6-based distros, there seems to be no Python3 package(s) to install, so you might have to find a workaround, but yes, `MySQLdb` *has* Python3 support. Since you already got Python3 working in CentOS, you might have to see if someone else has created an RPM for it or potentially build from source. Your non-standard Python3 path suggests you did not get Python3 from a CentOS repository, right?

Comment: Anzel/Ray - Thanks for the lead.  Your input is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.  Anzel was right about the fact that it's installed globally in the default python2.6 directory.  Here's how I fixed it:

Launch the default python interpreter, in my case "python" -> python2.6, and run the commands below to see where "MySQL.connector" was installed.

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print get_python_lib ()
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
>>>
```

Navigate to the above directory, "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/" reveal a directory called MySQL, and a file called, MySQL_connector_python-2.1.3-py2.6.egg-info.

Launching python3.5 interpreter leads me to a different path, which I checked and sure enough, the two MySQL and MySQL_connector_python-2.1.3-py2.6.egg-info file/directory wasn't there.

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> print (get_python_lib ())
/home/<username>/Documents/redhat-server/python_project/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages
>>>
```

Next, I copied those 2 files to Python3.5 site-packages directory, tested the import, database connections, and it worked!

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 13 2016, 17:43:34) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> 
>>> cnx = mysql.connector.connect (user = 'username', password = 'password', host = 'localhost',
               database = 'testdb')
>>> cnx
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at 0x7ffa4c1009b0>
```